# .emacs file issues with org-mode TODO tutorials

Tags: org-mode, init-file, terminal-emacs, todo

I am customizing my ~/.emacs file. Specifically, I am customizing org-mode's TODO list feature to include more tasks. However, I keep receiving the following error:

> File mode specification error: (wrong-type-argument stringp\ (sequence
>   "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "DONE"))

I've pasted my ~/.emacs file below. I am every new to emacs and org-mode. Would love any insights.

```el
;; -*- mode: emacs-lisp -*-                                 

;; Disable the splash screen (to enable it agin, replace th\
e t with 0)                                                 
(setq inhibit-splash-screen t)

;; Enable transient mark mode                               
(transient-mark-mode 1)

;;;;org-mode configuration                                  
;; Enable org-mode                                          
(require 'org)
(setq org-todo-keywords
  '((sequence "TODO" "IN-PROGRESS" "WAITING" "DONE")))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))


;; don't create backupfiles                                 
(setq make-backup-files nil)

;; don't create auto-save files                             
(setq auto-save-default nil)
```

Thanks -- any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `emacs --debug-init`?  Your code runs fine for me.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean.

Comment: What happens if you move `e t with 0 )` back up to the line where it is supposed to be (save and restart Emacs)?

Comment: I mean start emacs up with this flag enabled.  Then you get a backtrace when there is an error in the init file.

Comment: Hmm it just gives me the same error.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a general issue of usage norms, please do not post the same question simultaneously on Emacs.SE and stackoverflow.

Comment: You can use the shortcut `C-x C-e` to execute a lisp statement.  Use this to narrow the problem down to one line, and it will be easier to find a solution.

Comment: And when are you getting this error?  Is it when emacs starts, you open a file, or something else.

Comment: as @user2699 said, use `C-x C-e` at the end of `(setq org-todo-keywords ...)` to see if it executes correctly.  Alternately put the point anywhere in that statement and use `C-M-x`.

Answer (score 1):

The original poster has continued a comment from line 3 onto line 4 without placing the standard semicolon comment delimiter at the beginning of line 4.  The solution is to move `e t with 0)` on line 4 back up to line 3 where it belongs, or add at least one semicolon to the beginning of line 4. Then save the `.emacs` file and restart Emacs.

Comment: That gives a "Symbol's value as variable is void: e", rather than the error above, so I suspect that's a typo in copying the code to here.

Comment: @user2699 -- the other portions of the code are correct.  There's really only a few lines of code for us to work with, and the one I have cited in the answer is the only one that is incorrect.

Comment: True, but the error posted looks like it has something to do with org-todo-keywords, which makes me think the error must be with how the code is being called.

Comment: @user2699 -- I seem to remember an error back in the olden-days when `org-agenda-files` was not configured.  Do you think that could be it (i.e., that variable needs to be set correctly for everything to work out-of-the-box)?

Comment: That would be very odd.  The error seems to be related to the mode line, http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/elisp-manual-21/elisp_351.html, but I can't replicate it.